# PowerShell Suppress Output

Tags: powershell

I've checked and tried a few of the suggestions on StackOverflow but none of them seem to work.  I put together an example of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
[System.Random] $rand = New-Object System.Random
$randomNumbers = New-Object int[] 10;
[int[]] $randomNumbers;
for($i = 0; $i -lt $randomNumbers.Length; $i++)
{
    ($randomNumbers[$i] = $rand.Next(256)) 2>&1 | Out-Null;
}
```

I've tried the

```
> $Null
|Out-Null
2>&1
```

But none of them seem to suppress the output.  It's showing 10 zero's in a row.  One for each assignment.  How can I suppress that output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `int[]] $randomNumbers;`. It is not the assignment that is printed, but the empty array.

Comment: Doh!  Sorry for stupid mistake but thanks for the answer.  I'll accept when timer allows.  I hate these kind of stupid mistakes but really appreciate the quick answer that I've been banging my head against keyboard for 30 minutes.

Comment: I actually don't even need to suppress output.  $randomNumbers[$i] = $rand.Next(256) works just fine.  I thought that was what was outputting all the zeros

Answer (score 2):

other solution for replace your code ;)

```
 [int[]] $randomNumbers=1..10 | %{ Get-Random -maximum 256 }
```

Comment: ++; I was busy crafting my answer with essentially the same idea while you posted this. Note that `-Minimum` should be `0` (and can therefore be omitted) to match the behavior of [`Random.Next Method (Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd1bc8e5(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: then "Get-Random -maximum 256 " because 0 is default of minimum ;) i have modified my code

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Andrey Marchuk's effective answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40287343/45375):

- `[int[]] $randomNumbers` ***looks* like a type-bound PowerShell variable *declaration*, but, since *no value is assigned*, it is merely a *cast***: the preexisting value of `$randomNumbers` - a 10-element array of `0` values - is simply cast to `[int[]]` (a no-op in this case), and then *output* - yielding 10 lines with a `0` on each in this case.

  - A true type-bound assignment that is the (inefficient) equivalent of your `New-Object int[] 10` statement is `[int[]] $randomNumbers = @( 0 ) * 10`.
    Note that it is the presence of `= <value>` that makes this statement an *assignment* that implicitly creates the variable.
  - PowerShell has no variable *declarations* in the conventional sense, it creates variables on demand when you *assign* to them.
    You can, however, use the `New-Variable` cmdlet to explicitly create variables, which allows you to control additional aspects, such as the variable's scope.
- **Variable assignments in PowerShell do NOT output anything by default**, so there's no need to suppress any output (with `| Out-Null`, `>$null`, ...).
- That said, **you can *force* a variable assignment to output the assigned value by enclosing the assignment in `(...)`**.

  - `$v = 'foo' # no output`
  - `($v = 'foo') # enclosed in () -> 'foo' is output`

As you've discovered, actively suppressing the output in `($randomNumbers[$i] = $rand.Next(256)) 2>&1 | Out-Null;` is unnecessary, because simply omitting the parentheses makes the statement quiet: `$randomNumbers[$i] = $rand.Next(256)`

---

Finally, you could **simplify your code** using the `Get-Random` cmdlet:

```
[int[]] $randomNumbers = 1..10 | % { Get-Random -Maximum 256 }
```

This single pipeline does everything your code does (not sure about performance, but it may not matter).

Comment: Not really worried about performance.  I was more tinkering around while I learn more about PowerShell.  Thanks for your description on variable declaration.  I was struggling with declaring the array which is probably why I still had that extra line in there that was unneeded.